# Best way to spot non-GSM characters in a string?

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

There are other posts here re: Apex matcher functions and replacing characters in a string. I simply need to know if a given string contains any non-gsm chars. [GSM refers to a standardized set of characters used for mobile texting.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38) I don't need to know which char or index it is.

I found a regex for gsm that seems solid:

```
GSM_CHARACTERS_REGEX = "^[A-Za-z0-9 \\r\\n@£$¥èéùìòÇØøÅå\u0394_\u03A6\u0393\u039B\u03A9\u03A0\u03A8\u03A3\u0398\u039EÆæßÉ!\"#$%&amp;'()*+,\\-./:;&lt;=&gt;?¡ÄÖÑÜ§¿äöñüà^{}\\\\\\[~\\]|\u20AC]*$"
```

I'm thinking there must be something quicker than checking every char in my string -- something like the `some` property from Javascript?

Any ideas?

I would use a keyup event to test the latest char entered, but it's possible that users will paste in a string, or use a template that inputs the full string all at once.

I can handle this check either in Javascript on the client, or in Apex. Currently thinking that I'll create a const array of all the gsm chars, then immediately before sending to Apex, I'll use javascript `string.split("")` to create an array of all the letters, then create a set from that array, then loop through the set, checking to see if const gsm includes the char.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by GSM characters? I assume you refer to `Global System for Mobile Communications`, but it is not clear based on what I know of it how that would constrain your character set.

Comment: Yes, characters used for the most concise compression over mobile networks. Carriers will transmit up to 160 GSM chars as a single text. As soon as you throw in an emoji or other non-gsm, they switch to UCS-2 encoding, which has a limit of ~ 67 characters per text segment (phones typically receive multiple text segments and stitch them back together to display as a single text.) In my app, I need to test a string to determine (based on the presence of any non-gsm char) how many segments the message is.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it in the Javascript on the onchange for the text entry. It splits the string into a set to minimize the comparison, then back to an array where it filters that array against a const array of all gsm chars.

The gsmChars in my list [are documented on a number of sites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38). The challenge for me was coming up with the fastest way to check each char in a string against that list so it could happen with every new character entered. The bottom part of my handler is just the functional part of what I needed to do -- if there's a non-GSM character, indicated that the message will be broken into segments of up to 67 chars, else segments of 153 chars.

```
const gsmChars = [  'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
                'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
                'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
                'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
                '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
                '!', '#', ' ', '"', '%', '&', '\'', '(', ')', '*', ',', '.', '?',
                '+', '-', '/', ';', ':', '<', '=', '>', '¡', '¿', '_', '@',
                '$', '£', '¥', '¤',
                'è', 'é', 'ù', 'ì', 'ò', 'Ç', 'Ø', 'ø', 'Æ', 'æ', 'ß', 'É', 'Å',
                'å', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ñ', 'Ü', '§', 'ä', 'ö', 'ñ', 'ü', 'à',
                'Δ','Φ','Ξ','Γ','Ω','Π','Ψ','Σ','Θ','Λ'];

checkBody(event){
    let body = event.detail.value;
    this.charCount = body.length;
    let bodyCharSet = new Set(body.split(""));
    let bodyCharArray = Array.from(bodyCharSet);
    this.notGsm = ((bodyCharArray.filter(e => !gsmChars.includes(e)).length > 0));
    if(this.notGsm){
        this.segmentCount = Math.ceil(body.length / 67);
    }else {
        this.segmentCount = Math.ceil(body.length / 153);
    }
}
```

Comment: What led you to that character set? As written, this answer is still more or less a black box.

Comment: Edited for more context. Hope that helps...

Comment: These characters are not listed on the wikipedia entry for gsm. Rather than saying how easy it is to search for, it would be more useful to link to a specific canonical reference and cite the relevant content here.  I did search (in admittedly cursory fashion) and did not find this information.

Comment: I added a link to the wikipedia entry, plus there are: https://www.developershome.com/sms/gsmAlphabet.asp, https://www.clockworksms.com/blog/the-gsm-character-set/, https://www.smsmac.com/help/discover/about-sms/gsm7bit/, https://wire2air.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202667135-GSM-Encoding-and-Special-Characters, all of which are listed in the first page of google results for  "gsm characters".